# What is difference between $(basename $0) and "$(basename $0)"?

Tags: bash, shell

I have script code that I think they look the same, but they must work differently.

```
BASEDIR=$(basename $0)
    SN="$(basename $0)"
```

Following the reference, double quotes are

> How to suppress most of the interpretation of a sequence of characters.

In bash, I typed both, but the results are the same.
What is really a difference between these two?

Comment: These assignments are exactly the same, and both wrong. To fix the bugs, it would need to be `result=$(basename "$0")` (or `result="$(basename "$0")"`, which has the advantage that `"$(basename "$0")"` works correctly even in a non-assignment context).

Comment: ...try giving your script a name that contains whitespace to make those bugs more visible.

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is a good resource to go to first; it flags the issue in question with a link to [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: ...as another aside, it's bad form to use all-caps names for your script's own variables, as these names are used for variables that modify behavior of the shell and OS; see the relevant POSIX documentation @ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a local shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Comment: BTW, given the name `BASEDIR`, I'll bet the author meant to run `dirname`, not `basename`.